# Windows, libb64 and segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to use [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/) for encoding some text in base64.
Being on windows and being not able to install cygwin, I just put the files `cencode.h` and `cencode.c` in a lib which I import in QtCreator.

I then tried to encode a simple text in order to check if everything was fine. It was not.
Here is my little code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b64/cencode.h"

int main(void)
{
    char* textIn = "taratata";
    char* textOut;
    int len = 77;
    base64_encodestate state;
    base64_init_encodestate(&state);
    base64_encode_block(textIn, len, textOut, &state);
    printf(textOut);
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces a `segfault` when calling

```
int base64_encode_block(const char* plaintext_in, int length_in, char* code_out, base64_encodestate* state_in);
```

I'm pretty sure the lib itself is not at fault here, but I can't determine the root of this trouble. Since I can't find documentation for this method, I would appreciate help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for `out` using `malloc()`. Since you never initialized the pointer, it just points to garbage, not valid memory.

Comment: I guess I can't just skip from python to C wuthout some learning. Thanks !